# Android No value for JSONObject

Tags: android, json

```
String wat = "";

        try{
                JSONObject responsee = new JSONObject(result);
                wat = responsee.getString("Result");
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }
```

result = {"Result":"D"}

This code crashes application and throws following error:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for {"Result":"D"}`

Comment: can you print your responsee ?

Comment: Debugger shows: {"Result":"D"}

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond to the exception. Exception says that you passed string `{"Result":"D"}` to some `get` method while your code shows that you only use `getString` with `"Result"`. So please check your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`responsee` itself a json object you need. You don't need to call `getJSONObject` on it. Just use `responsee.getString("Result");`. Here is an example where you may need to use `getJsonObject`:

```
// result = {"name": "John", "age": 10, "father": {"name": "Tom", "age": 30"}}

JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject father = response.getJSONObject("father");
String fathersName = father.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
JSon Response like  below
 {"data": { "name": "AAA", "Age": "11"}}
```

You will use that code to get data below,

```
  JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONObject json= response.getJSONObject("data");
  String Name = json.getString("name");
  String Age =json.getString("Age");
```

Response is: AAA and 11